# How do I get the modified date/time of a file in Python?

Tags: python, file

How do I get the modified date/time of a file in Python?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
os.path.getmtime(filepath)
```

or

```
os.stat(filepath).st_mtime
```

Comment: @endolith: http://stackoverflow.com/a/237082/125507 says "os.path.getmtime() is made for this, and simpler."

Answer (score 20):

Formated:

```
import time
print time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(fname)))
```

Comment: ISO-like fmt: `"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"`