# Python: Get a list of all files and folders in a directory, the time of creation, the time of last modification. System independent solution?

Tags: python, datetime, directory, last-modified, filetime

This is a challenge as well as a question:

I have a folder of data files.
I want the following list of lists of information:

```
Filename:      Created:                     Last modified:

Information = 
[
[datafile1,    Mon Mar 04 10:45:24 2013,    Tue Mar 05 12:05:09 2013],
[datafile2,    Mon Mar 04 11:23:02 2013,    Tue Apr 09 10:57:55 2013],
[datafile2.1,  Mon Mar 04 11:37:21 2013,    Tue Apr 02 15:35:58 2013],
[datafile3,    Mon Mar 04 15:36:13 2013,    Thu Apr 18 15:03:25 2013],
[datafile4,    Mon Mar 11 09:20:08 2013,    Mon May 13 16:30:59 2013]
]
```

I can sort it myself after I have the Information.
Can someone write the function:

```
def get_information(directory):
    .
    .
    .
    return Information
```

These posts are useful:

1)  [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)

2)  [Sorting files by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759415/sorting-files-by-date)

3)  [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python?rq=1)

4)  [Python: sort files by datetime in more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943858/python-sort-files-by-datetime-in-more-details?lq=1)

5)  [Sorting files by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759415/sorting-files-by-date?lq=1)

6)  [How do I get the modified date/time of a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121025/how-do-i-get-the-modified-date-time-of-a-file-in-python?lq=1)

However: I feel there must exist a better, more re-usable solution which works on windows, and linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know for a fact that `os.stat` functions well on both `windows` and `linux`.

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

However, to fit your functionality, you could do:

You can use `st_atime` to access most recent access and `st_ctime` for file creation time.

```
import os,time

def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.listdir(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        file_list.append([i,time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) #[file,most_recent_access,created]
    return file_list

print get_information("/")
```

I'm on a `mac` and I get this,

```
[['.dbfseventsd', 'Thu Apr  4 18:39:35 2013', 'Thu Apr  4 18:39:35 2013'], ['.DocumentRevisions-V100', 'Wed May 15 00:00:00 2013', 'Sat Apr 13 18:11:00 2013'],....]
```

Comment: For me both atime and ctime return the created date. My files are in a Windows 8.1 NTFS directory and I'm running Python 2.7