# Writing a list of creation time of items in a folder

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to write a text file with the creation date of each file in a directory. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595081/python-get-a-list-of-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-the-time-of-creation) question, but I'm still in need of help, besides being curious about why the code below doesn't work.

I think I'm close. It kind of works with the creation date of the *folder*, but I want to know when the *files* were created.

```
import os, os.path, time, datetime    
mydir = '/home/user/ebay/'
mydir2 = '/home/user/'
def writefiles():
    with open(mydir2 + '/items.txt', "wb") as a:
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
            for file in files:
                a.write(file+' , '+(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))) + os.linesep)
writefiles()
```

I get this error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PkV20ZrzMs'
```

This is odd, because there is a file called 'PkV20ZrzMs'. I tried to add the directory location but it didn't make any difference.

The reason I think I'm close is that when I change `(os.path.getctime(file)` to `(os.path.getctime(path)` I get the creation date of the folder, like this:

```
PkV20ZrzMs , Fri Mar 20 13:43:31 2015
qZzo0ZUAtm , Fri Mar 20 13:43:31 2015
Tm5f8Lhgcd , Fri Mar 20 13:43:31 2015
vgMCBGdJu0 , Fri Mar 20 13:43:31 2015
Ja7Bwa5uEi , Fri Mar 20 13:43:31 2015
```

Comment: Did you add the directory location with `os.path.join(dirpath, file)` for each `file` in `files`?

Comment: Yes, and I tried again just now. It doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me, so perhaps there's something up with your path? Note that you have a trailing slash in your `mydir2` that might mess up the path you're writing to when you concatenate `'/items.txt'`.

```
import os, os.path, time, datetime    

mydir = '/home/xnx/temp'
mydir2 = '/tmp'

def writefiles():
    with open(mydir2 + '/items.txt', "wb") as a:
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
            for file in files:
                a.write(file+' , '+(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(
                           os.path.join(path, file)))) + os.linesep)
writefiles()
```